# How can I pit a bowlful of olives?

Tags: food

I kind of understand how you might remove the stone from one olive but how are mass produced olives pitted but remain intact when I buy them or is it genetically modified somehow? I want to try to pit a load of olives myself but don't want to break them up

Comment: This does not seem to be asking for a lifehack.

Comment: This isn't the right place for this question but they're not GM, no, they're pitted by a machine, having previously been placed in a chemical solution to make them a bit firmer so they don't break apart so easily when the machine pushes the stone out.

Comment: Just trying to find out how to do it myself. Whats the chemical solution?

Comment: Don't know about olives myself (as they don't grow hereabouts), but I think cherries are quite similar.  They sell cherry-pitting machines, or you can just use a chopstick or similar to push the stone out.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate, and will most certainly receive better answers, on http://cooking.stackexchange.com/. General cooking advice isn't really a life hack.

Comment: oh i see. it gets downvoted at the same time i said this forum is struggling to define itself on another question. revenge downvoting. pretty sad really

Comment: Try checking an ingredients list from a can of pre-pitted olives for the "chemical solution"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Good-Grips-Cherry-Olive-Pitter/dp/B000NQ925K/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1433012070&sr=8-1&keywords=cherry%20pitter%20stoner) is a Cherry/Olive pitter on Amazon UK.

I've tried using one in the past and I found it to be quite difficult. I understand the factories tend to do them whilst slight under-ripe. If you use it on soft ones they tend to squish rather too easily.

Having said that, I've spoken to someone who told me that they can use one on soft cherries with no problem so maybe you'd get used to it after a while.